# help_text for username and email fields always output in browser

Tags: django

I have this model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email address'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters of fewer. Must be a valid email address.'),
        error_messages={
            'unique':_("A user with that email address already exists."),
        },
    )
```

this form class:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password']
```

this view class:

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'workoutcal/register.html'

    def get(self, request):
        print("Hi again")
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:

                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('workoutcal:calendar')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

and this url:

```
url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register')
```

So when I go to `/workoutcal/register`, I see this:

[image]

The "help text" is always shown in the browser. Is this default Django behaviour, or is it due to some error I have made?

Also, how do I make the text only show up if the user has entered bad data into the respective fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Yes** if you are using `{{ form }}` in your template

It will always show `help_text`, `label`, `errors` and `widget` automatically

If you don't want that you need to render `form` manually by [**`looping over fields`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields)

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
       {{ hidden_field.errors }}
       {{ hidden_field }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
           {{ field.errors }}
           {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
           {{ field.help_text }} <!-- remove this line if you don't want to show it in your html.-->
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> For more read docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/